# Profile images to Active Directory

Tags: powershell

I'm in the position that I have to run a skatulated job where we have a lot of profile images to be connected to our AD user.

User and the pictures have the same name so i want a powerhell that can associate all the users with their profile picture is it possible?

I have made one here that takes each one but would like to have it automated.

Here is sample code:

```
$ Photo = [byte []] (Get-Content "C: \ temp \ crusoe.jpg" -Encoding byte)
Set-ADUser Crusoe -Replace @ {thumbnailPhoto = $ photo}
```

Comment: FWIW, I try to avoid this. The ldap engine here just isn't that good at handling "large" binary items. It can significantly impact performance. I do like to have profile images for my user accounts, but I actually find it preferable to set the image in numerous downstream apps, painful as that is, over storing in AD.

Answer (score 0):

Get all of the photos you want to use, loop over them with foreach. Then if the photo is the same name as the user, then the `BaseName` property from the `Get-ChildItem` will be the name of the user:

```
$FilePath = "C:\temp\"
$Photos = Get-ChildItem $FilePath -include .jpg
foreach ($Photo in $Photos) {
    $thumbnailPhoto = [byte[]](Get-Content $Photo.Fullname -Encoding byte) 
    Set-ADUser $Photo.basename -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto = $thumbnailPhoto}
}
```